# Split nested list with dictionary into columns based on key value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out how to create columns based in the first item of a nested dictionary of a column and then place the value based on the second value of the dictionary.

Reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 'nestedlist':[[{'code':1,'value':10},{'code':2,'value':20}],
                                            [{'code':2,'value':10},{'code':3,'value':20}],
                                            [{'code':1,'value':10},{'code':2,'value':20}],
                                            [{'code':1,'value':10},{'code':3,'value':20}]]})
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
# desired DataFrame
   ID code1 code2 code3
0  1  10    20    NaN
1  2  NaN   10    20
2  3  10    20    NaN
3  4  10    NaN   20
```

Comment: The output came from a geoprocess, so the input is a dataframe and the result is a json. The function itself bind the product into the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `explode` on `nestedlist` columns and convert dict column to multi columns with `pd.Series`. Then `pivot` table.

```py
df_ = df.explode('nestedlist')
df_ = pd.concat([df_['ID'], df_['nestedlist'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df_ = df_.pivot(index='ID', columns='code', values='value').add_prefix('code').reset_index()
```

```
print(df_)

code  ID  code1  code2  code3
0      1   10.0   20.0    NaN
1      2    NaN   10.0   20.0
2      3   10.0   20.0    NaN
3      4   10.0    NaN   20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `explode` the column and `pivot` it; then `join` it back to `df`:

```
exploded = df['nestedlist'].explode()
out = (df[['ID']].join(pd.pivot(pd.DataFrame(exploded.tolist(), index=exploded.index)
                                .reset_index(), 'index','code','value')
                       .add_prefix('code')))
```

Output:

```
   ID  code1  code2  code3
0   1   10.0   20.0    NaN
1   2    NaN   10.0   20.0
2   3   10.0   20.0    NaN
3   4   10.0    NaN   20.0
```